# How to recode a variable to numeric?

Tags: r, r-car

```
> library(car)

> df = data.frame(value=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'))
> foo = recode(df$value, "'A'=1; 'B'=2; 'C'=3;", as.numeric.result=TRUE)
> mean(foo)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(foo) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> foo
[1] 1 2 3 1
Levels: 1 2 3
```

Ugh. I thought the [definition of as.numeric.result](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/car/html/recode.html) (default TRUE) was that if the results are all numerals, they would be coerced to numeric.

How do I get the results of this recoding to be numeric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look carefully at the documentation on `recode` you'll see this:

```
as.factor.result     return a factor; default is TRUE if var is a factor, FALSE otherwise.
as.numeric.result    if TRUE (the default), and as.factor.result is FALSE, 
                      then the result will be coerced to numeric if all values in the 
                      result are numerals—i.e., represent numbers.
```

So you need to specify `as.factor.result=FALSE` I think:

```
foo = recode(df$value, "'A'=1; 'B'=2; 'C'=3;", as.factor.result=FALSE)
```

*edit* 
Since the default of `as.numeric.result` is TRUE, you only need to specify `as.factor.result=FALSE`, rather than specifying both of them.

Comment: I have a similar question, but I have been working on it for more than one hour, searching on the websites. My question is *What if the value is ' >50K' and ' <=50K'*. In his case, just like `foo = recode(df$value, "' >A'=1; ' >B'=2; ' >C'=3;")`, please note **>** or **<** mark. I am struggling with these two marks. I cannot post another question, because it will be considered as duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `as.numeric` again

```
> bar <- as.numeric(foo)
> bar
[1] 1 2 3 1
> str(bar)
 num [1:4] 1 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

From `?recode` you should note what is said about the `as.numeric.result` argument:

```
as.factor.result: return a factor; default is ‘TRUE’ if ‘var’ is a
          factor, ‘FALSE’ otherwise.

as.numeric.result: if ‘TRUE’ (the default), and ‘as.factor.result’ is
          ‘FALSE’, then the result will be coerced to numeric if all
          values in the result are numerals-i.e., represent numbers.
```

`as.factor.result` defaults to `TRUE` so the result will always be a factor, regardless of what you set `as.numeric.result` to. To get the desired behaviour, set both `as.factor.result = FALSE` **and** `as.numeric.result = TRUE`:

```
> recode(df$value, "'A'=1; 'B'=2; 'C'=3;", as.numeric.result=TRUE, 
         as.factor.result = FALSE)
[1] 1 2 3 1
```